# How to interpret p-values in terms of correlation?

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance, p-value, computational-statistics, spearman-rho

I have one datamatrix and a single column(let's say it fvector). I had find the spearman's correlation of each column from datamatrix with fvector i had setted the parameters as p <0.05 and i got the p values as:

1) 1.8825324437802993e-171

2) 4.948172998549518e-166

3) 3.0039056895428945e-163

4) 4.6655794480181464e-160

5) 6.545563116209527e-160

6) 7.164774375961699e-160

7) 5.932428304260942e-159

8) 6.086200937454601e-157

9) 2.0346341192857495e-126

10) 5.9272205339906955e-120

but I don't know how to interpret these values. Can Any one tell me which values is will be considered as most correlated. Also what is more important to consider a better correlation P-value or correlation coefficient ?

Answer (score 1):

As a practical matter, all of these are *de facto* 0, even the largest is 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000059 (5.9e-120 means zero point hundert and twenty zeros five nine). So you cannot use them to distinguish one from the other.

More fundamentally, a $p$-value is not there to say anything about the size of an effect. Instead a $p$-value is an (imperfect) attempt to quantify the strength of the evidence against a certain hypothesis. If you are interested in the size of the effect, you will need to look at that. Depending on the situation this could be a (Spearman's) correlation.

Comment: ok but still if i have to conclude from this data only then which values will have stronger corrlelation then other .?

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you want to compare correlations, then the obvious solution is to compare correlations and not to compare some other statistic (e.g. $p$-values).